# Connecting IOS firebase app to my flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I am trying to connect a IOS Firebase app to my flutter and the packages I am importing come up with the error "The library 'package:firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.
Try migrating the imported library".

Comment: Looks like your version of this package lower than null safety try to update to latest version or you can remove null safety.

Comment: I have done that but now it comes up with/Running "flutter pub get" in project...                         
The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1.

Because project depends on cloud_firestore >=3.1.10 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because project depends on cloud_firestore >=3.1.10 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1/

Comment: It is still saying they are legacy

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The title of the question and the problem you stated in the description and comments are not related. Try to change the question's title. @JackHillyer

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one problem as per your description and comments.
The easiest solution is to upgrade the dart, flutter, and all the dependencies you are using because it seems that you are using all the things which are older.

First, in your command prompt (terminal), run:

```
> flutter upgrade
```

This will upgrade your flutter and dart both. Secondly, run:

```
> flutter pub upgrade
```

This will upgrade all the dependencies. Finally, run:

```
> flutter pub upgrade --major-version
```

This will also upgrade all the dependencies.

Doing these will make your application up to date with the dependencies. Now, try to run the app again. Most probably it will work, if it doesn't then it might tell you to upgrade your compileSdkVersion in build.gradle to something larger number. If so, upgrade that number in your app>build.gradle file.